# Downgrading function of Java 8 to Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, java-stream

I have started to learn Java with current version 1.8. This means I use function that appears in this version and I don't know how things were going on before...

I would like someone tell me how to do the equivalent of this in java 7 please :

I have a Person object which contains a float value attribute. I want to find the min/max value of this value out of a list of "Person". This is how I did in Java 8 with parallelStream :

```
Person max = people.parallelStream().max(Comparator.comparing(p-> ((Person) p).getFloatValue())).get()
```

Comment: You could use a `for` loop

Comment: I guess so but there is not a "proper" way in java 7 ?

Comment: That is the proper way, because Java 7 doesn't have Java 8's functional features. Otherwise we wouldn't have needed Java 8.

Comment: Do NOT use parallelStream. It creates separate threads that is time consuming. It is useful only under some circumstances but for sure not here. Use just stream()

Comment: Ok good to know for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the person where that value is maximized, you could write a loop over the list, and then check each value.

```
 Person maxPerson = people.get(0); // get's the first person
 for(int i = 1; i < people.size(); i ++) // loop over list, finding max
 {
    if(people.get(i).getFloatValue() > maxPerson.getFloatValue())
       maxPerson = people.get(i); 
 }
 // now maxPerson stores the person where this value is the highest
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution even if others are also interesting ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain for loop and if-else checks to do this.
A more elegant approach would be to use [Guava Ordering](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained).

```
Ordering<Person> personOrdering = new Ordering<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person left, Person right) {
        return Floats.compare(left.getFloatValue(), right.getFloatValue());
    }
};
Person max =  personOrdering.max(list);
Person min =  personOrdering.min(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it:

```
Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {

  public int compare(People o1, Person o2) {
    return ((Float)o1.getFloatValue()).compareTo(o2.getFloatValue());
  }
};

Person max = Collections.max(persons, comparator);
Person min = Collections.min(persons, comparator);
```